# how to let magento send different mails with different information for every payment method

Tags: html, email, magento, payment

My New Order email already uses {{var payment_html}} and I already have a custom note for customers who select MoneyGram, Western Union and Money Transfer payment methods. I need to send different information for every single payment method in the email being sent.

Answer (score 0):

you need to override `sendNewOrderEmail()` in  `/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/order.php`

in this function just check the payment and dynamically pass the value to array.

```
public function sendNewOrderEmail()
{
    $storeId = $this->getStore()->getId();

    if (!Mage::helper('sales')->canSendNewOrderEmail($storeId)) {
        return $this;
    }
    // Get the destination email addresses to send copies to
    $copyTo = $this->_getEmails(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_COPY_TO);
    $copyMethod = Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_COPY_METHOD, $storeId);

    // Start store emulation process
    $appEmulation = Mage::getSingleton('core/app_emulation');
    $initialEnvironmentInfo = $appEmulation->startEnvironmentEmulation($storeId);

    try {
        // Retrieve specified view block from appropriate design package (depends on emulated store)
        $paymentBlock = Mage::helper('payment')->getInfoBlock($this->getPayment())
            ->setIsSecureMode(true);
        $paymentBlock->getMethod()->setStore($storeId);
        $paymentBlockHtml = $paymentBlock->toHtml();
    } catch (Exception $exception) {
        // Stop store emulation process
        $appEmulation->stopEnvironmentEmulation($initialEnvironmentInfo);
        throw $exception;
    }

    // Stop store emulation process
    $appEmulation->stopEnvironmentEmulation($initialEnvironmentInfo);

    // Retrieve corresponding email template id and customer name
    if ($this->getCustomerIsGuest()) {
        $templateId = Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_GUEST_TEMPLATE, $storeId);
        $customerName = $this->getBillingAddress()->getName();
    } else {
        $templateId = Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_TEMPLATE, $storeId);
        $customerName = $this->getCustomerName();
    }

    $mailer = Mage::getModel('core/email_template_mailer');
    $emailInfo = Mage::getModel('core/email_info');
    $emailInfo->addTo($this->getCustomerEmail(), $customerName);
    if ($copyTo && $copyMethod == 'bcc') {
        // Add bcc to customer email
        foreach ($copyTo as $email) {
            $emailInfo->addBcc($email);
        }
    }
    $mailer->addEmailInfo($emailInfo);

    // Email copies are sent as separated emails if their copy method is 'copy'
    if ($copyTo && $copyMethod == 'copy') {
        foreach ($copyTo as $email) {
            $emailInfo = Mage::getModel('core/email_info');
            $emailInfo->addTo($email);
            $mailer->addEmailInfo($emailInfo);
        }
    }
    // $orde$this->getOrderId();
    $order_payment_title = $this->getOrder()->getPayment()->getMethodInstance()->getTitle();
    if($order_payment_title=='moneygram'){
        $paymentBlockHtml = 'moneygram html'; //custom html
    }elseif($order_payment_title=='westernunion'){
        $paymentBlockHtml = 'westernunion html'; //custom html
    }elseif($order_payment_title=='monyetransfer  '){
        $paymentBlockHtml = 'monyetransfer  html'; //custom html
    }
    // Set all required params and send emails
    $mailer->setSender(Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_IDENTITY, $storeId));
    $mailer->setStoreId($storeId);
    $mailer->setTemplateId($templateId);
    $mailer->setTemplateParams(array(
            'order'        => $this,
            'billing'      => $this->getBillingAddress(),
            'payment_html' => $paymentBlockHtml

        )
    );
    $mailer->send();

    $this->setEmailSent(true);
    $this->_getResource()->saveAttribute($this, 'email_sent');

    return $this;
}
```

Comment: Hi Manoj Im sorry I was a little late to reply. As much as the code seems flawless ,It keeps me returning back to shopping cart without sending any mails.Any Idea?

Comment: please add log to sendNewOrderEmail() function for debugging.